# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-3 t}}{t} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral

> $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-3 t}}{t} \, dt$$

Can we evaluate it using complex integral?

Comment: I can see why this was put on hold but the quality of the two answers seems like a strong argument in favor of reopening. So I am voting to do that. Evidently the answerers felt the question had some mathematical interest, despite lack of context.

Answer (score 11):

This is a special case of [Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). But there's a simple direct way: $$\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-3t}}t\,dt=\int^\infty_0\int^3_1e^{-xt}\,dx\,dt=\int^3_1\int^\infty_0e^{-xt}\,dt\,dx=\int^3_1\frac1x\,dx=\ln3.$$ There's no point in making this any more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to exploit [a core property of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis). We have
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-t})=\frac{1}{s+1},\qquad \mathcal{L}(e^{-3t})=\frac{1}{s+3},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=1$$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-3t}}{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{1}{s+3}\right)\,ds=\lim_{M\to +\infty}\left[\log\frac{s+1}{s+3}\right]_{0}^{M}=\log 3. $$